# Smoothscroll doesn't work in chrome but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I have a button (it is a Font awesome icon), which if you click on it it scrolls to a specific div. In Safari it worked but now I am testing it in Chrome it doesn't work.

**The script I am using (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

**The button**

```
<a href="#arrow-down-click">
<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-4x arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

How to get this working in Chrome (and maybe other browsers I didn't tested yet) too?

**EDIT (also in a comment):**

I just found out: if I change in css `html { overflow: hidden; }` to `auto` and `body { overflow: auto; }` to `hidden`, the animation works. But the problem is: I can't scroll from the top down without using the button to go to part 2, and if I am on part 2 I can't scroll anywhere (so not back to the top or to part 3).. Does someone has an idea for that?

**EDIT 2**
Right now I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/jk1540oc/.
It goes to the div I direct to, but it doesn't animate anymore (not in Chrome and not in Safari). You also can't scroll down twice by using the button.

Comment: What, exactly, does `it doesn't work` mean? How doesn't it work? What are you expecting vs what happens? etc.

Comment: @phuzi In safari you see it scrolling down very nice and smooth. In chrome it takes a second or so and you see the div out of no where instead of scrolling smooth

Comment: I just found out: if I change in css html { overflow: hidden; } to auto and body   { overflow: auto; } to hidden, the animation works. But the problem is: I can't scroll from the top down without using the button to go to part 2, and if I am on part 2 I can't scroll anywhere (so not back to the top or to part 3).. Does someone has an idea for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend keeping `html, body { overflow: hidden, height: 100% }` and then a wrapper div with `{ overflow: auto; height: 100% }`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="site-wrapper"> everything in here </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a pattern I have used for a very long time and it has saved me a lot of headache. Then, do all of your scrolling animations on the div. Here's a working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/b4uje52o/2/

Comment: Thank you! It scrolls now: so thank you very much! But there is one problem.. When you are not totally at the top of the page but you can click the button it only brings you down a bit and not to the whole target div and if you click than again it goes back up a bit. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1b1pj91q/

Comment: You have to adjust the logic for determining the scroll position. Here's an example with the calculations fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/1b1pj91q/1/

Answer (score 4):

[Follow image description with steps numbered here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCmtK.jpg)

How to Enable or Disable Smooth Scrolling in Google Chrome in Windows

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Copy and paste the link below into the address bar of Chrome, and press Enter.

`chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling`

3. Select Default, Enabled, or Disabled for the Smooth Scrolling setting you want.

The Default setting has smooth scrolling enabled, but it could automatically disable smooth scrolling when you have too many tabs open.

Comment: +1 Your last comment is the real answer here.  Never knew Chrome disabled smooth scrolling when too many tabs are open. Smooth scrolling never works for me because I always have so many tabs.

Comment: It's just weird that they don't fall back to auto scrolling. Now no scrolling is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the initial question was slightly vague.  However, I had a similar issue with Chrome not implementing Smoothscrolling using Javascript.  I was able to solve the issue by simply replacing the #link with the full link in the html.

From your question:

`<a href="#arrow-down-click">
<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-4x arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>`

I changed `#arrow-down-click` to `http://www.yourURLhere.com/#arrow-down-click`